Why do we use super() while creating custom exceptions in Java?
If we use super() to access Throwable class' printStackTrace() method as that is what is used by DefaultExceptionHandler, then that could be done with this also as because of inheritance, printStackTrace is available in our own custom defined exception class as well.
Please let me know if I got something wrong?
class AlsCustomException extends Exception
{
    public AlsCustomException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}

Consider this code snippet above. super is a reference variable that points to the object of super class created automatically when an instance of the child class in created then, what is super()..?
class AlsCustomException extends Exception
{
    public AlsCustomException(String message)
    {
        this(message);
    }
}

I am expecting that above code snippet should work just as fine as well.

"super is a reference variable that points to the object of super class created automatically when an instance of the child class in created" - no it's not?

The this(message); version won't compile: Recursive constructor invocation

"I am expecting that above code snippet should work just as fine as well"  This is something you could easily try, and should have tried before asking. If you had compiled the version with  this(message); , you could have seen the error message, searched, and then have discovered this question and others.

"what is super()?" - It is syntax for chaining to a constructor in the immediate superclass.  It is different from super. which is also not what you think it is.  Please don't try to learn Java by guesswork.  Take the time to take a decent Java tutorial or read a decent Java text book.  (Or if learning properly is too much effort for you ... Google for "Java constructor chaining".)

The 2nd code sample tries to recursively call the same AlsCustomException constructor over and over. It doesn't compile, but if it did, it would die with a StackOverflowException. In the 1st code block, super(...) calls the the parent class constructor, i.e., the Exception constructor.
You can call a method with the super keyword as well, to explicitly call the base class' method. This only makes sense when the current class overwrites it, so unless you overwrite printStackTrace, super.printStackTrace() and this.printStackTrace() and plain old printStackTrace() call the  same method.
See the Java tutorial.
